# Как преобразовать ссылки .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, link

Есть ссылки формата:

```
site.com/test.php?id=test
```

Как из нее сделать такой формат?

```
site.com/test/
```

`/test/` - это `id=TEST`.

Comment: А вы точно хотите этого? Или все-таки вы ЧПУ хотите организовать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Может быть вы хотите в итоге реализовать стандартный паттерн «[точка входа](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/front-controller.html)» ("front controller")? Это когда у вас единственный скрипт, обычно `/index.php` в корне, принимает и обрабатывает все запросы.

Для Apache конфиг `.htaccess` выглядит примерно так:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Это перекинет все запросы к несуществующим физически папкам или файлам на `index.php`. Уже в нём вам захочется узнать, какой же «красивый» url запрашивали – для этого смотрите переменную [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php) – она будет содержать что-то вроде `/test/` для вашего примера. Что с этим делать дальше – решать вам.

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>`

@sergiks сделал так, как теперь подтянуть стили?

пишу так, не работает: 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/assets/(.*).css`

Comment: Для стилей ничего специально прописывать не нужно: если запрошенный файл физически существует на сервере, правила Rewrite из ответа к нему не применятся.

Comment: У меня ссылка такая:
site.com/test.php?views=test
Преобразованная в 
site.com/test/
Теперь все стили идут на эту страницу так: 
site.com/test/asset/style.css 
а должна быть: site.com/asset/style.css 
Помоги исправить @Sergiks

Comment: Задайте отдельный вопрос, где приведите ваш нынешний `.htaccess`

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453529/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-htaccess

Вот @Sergiks сделал.

Answer (score 1):

Исправленный вариант.
Все от `=` до `&` или конца строки будет переведено в url

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/? [L,R]
```

Только желательно поставить больше условий. Ваш `id` будет всегда числовой? Или всегда текстовый?

Comment: Думаете, теперь стало лучше? Вы уж протестируйте предлагаемый `.htaccess` на локалхосте с различными входными данными, а не на одном `test.php?id=test`.

Comment: @Visman - проверил. последний вариант на локалке работает :)
спасибо

Comment: Угу, вы там это проверьте `/eeeeeeeeeeee?id=1&ttt=zero`

Comment: :):):):):):):) ну и получается `site.com/1&ttt=zero/`. В принципе, это тоже попадает под условия вопроса. Поэтому я и написал, что желательно больше условий... Но я понял, что вы имеете ввиду :) Сейчас подправим :)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ test.php?id=$1
```