# Как настроить ссылки стилей .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, link

Есть такой код в .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

У меня ссылка `site.com/test.php?views=test`, преобразованная в `site.com/test/`

Теперь все стили идут на эту страницу так: 
`site.com/test/asset/style.css`, а должна быть: `site.com/asset/style.css`

Как решить проблему?

Делал так:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/assets/(.*).css
```

Не помогает...(

Answer (score 1):

все стили **в HTML коде** должны идти на `/asset/style.css`

**К правилам mod_rewrite это отношения не имеет.** Это базовые правила по работе со ссылками. Все внутренние ссылки в HTML должны быть абсолютными - то есть, начинаться от корня сайта. В этом случае браузер всегда будет корректно отображать их. Никаких новых правил для статических файлов писать не надо. Строчка

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

УЖЕ обрабатывает их корректно, не давая выполнить редирект. Всё что надо - это проверить урл на опечатки, а сам файл - на существование.

Печально, что на хабре висят бессмысленные статьи о том, как решать несуществующие проблемы.

Comment: Плюс надо проверить на опечатки, asset или assets

Comment: Спасибо, понял)
НО, @Ипатьев
http://habrahabr.ru/post/115389/
тут написано как это делать, но у меня не выходит.

Comment: @user3608884, формируйте в **php** правильно ссылки все в виде `http://ваш.сайт/путь/до/файла.css`

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь, но про ссылки я сам понял и это НЕ ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ ОТВЕТОМ который мне нужен был. На хабре показано как решить мой вопрос, но сделал так же и не работает.
@Ипатьев Вопрос закрыт, спасибо.